# getting a value within a span in jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, tags

Here is my html tag,

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rdPayOutstanding"></asp:Label><br />
```

i wish to retrieve the value which is within the span tags and display it in a textbox, I have written the code below but it doesnt seem to work.

Can anyone help with what the issue with my code is ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var amount = $('#rdPayOutstanding').text().toString();
console.log(amount);
$('.textfield').val(amount);
$('.jsPayOutstanding').click(function () {
    $('.textfield').val(amount);
});

$('.jsPaySomeBalance').click(function () {
    // alert('yes');
    $('.textfield').val('');
});
});
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: The ID of an ASP.Net control is not the same as the client ID (the ID when rendered in the client).  Inspect your document at client-side to see what the ID is and use that instead, or give it a CssClass attribute and use that value.

Comment: Show the rendered html, not the asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using ASP.NET and when the controls render the ASP.NET engine modifies the ID of the resulting HTML elements.

You can add an attribute [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to get the "correct" id:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="rdPayOutstanding" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label><br />
```

Another approach is to use the attribute [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) and select by class instead:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="rdPayOutstanding" CssClass="rdPayOutstanding"></asp:Label><br />
```

Comment: Provided the OP has VS 2010 or above.

Comment: @freebird: For `ClientIDMode` VS 2010 is not required, only .NET Framework 4 or later. `CssClass` works in all versions of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the value using client id of the label as shown below

```
var amount = $('#<%=rdPayOutstanding.ClientID%>').val();
console.log(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be assign a `CSS` `class` to the `ASP.NET` `Label`

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="rdPayOutstanding" class="mylabel"></asp:Label>
```

Then you can do something like this

```
var amount = $('.mylabel').text();
```

**Note:**

The reason why you are not able to get the value of that label is because its client `ID` might have changed when rendered,try inspecting the element and find its `ID`.

Comment: asp:Label has no attribute named `class`.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen You can assign class to a ASP.NET label as it will get rendered as span with that class.

Comment: Yes. But you should differentiate between ASP.NET and HTML controls and attributes. Not mixing them. Generated HTML looks bad if you add both `class` and `CssClass`. It will render the `class` attribute twice. Since ASP.NET provides an appropriate attribute you should use it.

Comment: Another problem is that you can't access the `class` attribute from code behind. If you want to programmatically change the class you change `CssClass`, then where ever you use `class` will never be changed and now you've got two classes assigned to the element.

Answer (score -1):

Is `.textfield` a form element or not?

> $('.textfield').val(amount);

Sets the value attribute of an element, not the text,

If it isn't a form element, try

> $('.textfield').text(amount);

or if you want to want to add markup:

> $('.textfield').html('<strong>' + amount + '</strong>'); // or
>   whatever